# Devise suddenly not work with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an ActionCable project that uses Devise for authentication and is working fine.  I cloned the application and now I get this error:

ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
key must be 32 bytes

Extracted source (around line #72):

```
  cipher = new_cipher
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = @secret

  # Rely on OpenSSL for the initialization vector
  iv = cipher.random_iv
```

I checked the gemlock files of both applications and they are exactly the same.  Both applications are running on Cloud 9.  The Rails gem is 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.1'

I have another ActionCable project that suddenly quit working with the newest version of Rails 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

this error resolved by using rails 5.0.2 FYI: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25448

Comment: Thanks, but why does it not happen in both application.  In addition, devise is not working with another Rails application running 5.0.2 there we have a problem very similar to the one described here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4515